# Is it true that Swami Vivekananda advocated for a new dharmashastra for the modern age?

Tags: dharma-shastras, vivekananda

Is it true that Swami Vivekananda felt the need and opined that a new dharmashastra should be written for the modern age? I heard this. Is there any reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

> **CONVERSATIONS AND DIALOGUES** (From the Diary of a Disciple (Shri Sharat
> Chandra Chakravarty, B.A.))
>
> XI (Translated from Bengali )
>
> [Place: The Belur Math (under construction). Year: 1899.]
>
> Disciple: Why is it, Swamiji, that our society and country have come
> to such degradation?
>
> Swamiji: It is you who are responsible for it.
>
> Disciple: How, sir? You surprise me.
>
> Swamiji: You have been despising the lower classes of the country for
> a very long time and, as a result, you have now become the objects of
> contempt in the eyes of the world.
>
> Disciple: When did you find us despising them?
>
> Swamiji: Why, you priest-class never let the non-Brahmin class read
> the Vedas and Vedanta and all such weighty Shastras — never touch them
> even. You have only kept them down. It is you who have always done
> like that through selfishness. It was the Brahmins who made a monopoly
> of the religious books and kept the question of sanction and
> prohibition in their own hands. And repeatedly calling the other races
> of India low and vile, they put this belief into their heads that they
> were really such. If you tell a man, "You are low, you are vile", in
> season and out of season, then he is bound to believe in course of
> time that he is really such. This is called hypnotism. The non-Brahmin
> classes are now slowly rousing themselves. Their faith in Brahminical
> scriptures and Mantras is getting shaken. Through the spread of
> Western education all the tricks of the Brahmins are giving way, like
> the banks of the Padmâ in the rainy season. Do you not see that?
>
> Disciple: Yes, sir, the stricture of orthodoxy is gradually lessening
> nowadays.
>
> Swamiji: It is as it should be. The Brahmins, in fact, gradually took
> a course of gross immorality and oppression. Through selfishness they
> introduced a large number of strange, non-Vedic, immoral, and
> unreasonable doctrines — simply to keep intact their own prestige. And
> the fruits of that they are reaping forthwith.
>
> Disciple: What may these fruits be, sir?
>
> Swamiji: Don't you perceive them? It is simply due to your having
> despised the masses of India that you have now been living a life of
> slavery for the last thousand years; it is therefore that you are the
> objects of hatred in the eyes of foreigners and are looked upon with
> indifference by your countrymen.
>
> Disciple: But, sir, even now it is the Brahmins who direct all
> ceremonials, and people are observing them according to the opinions
> of the Brahmins. Why then do you speak like that?
>
> Swamiji: I don't find it. Where do the tenfold Samskâras or purifying
> ceremonies enjoined by the Shastras obtain still? Well, I have
> travelled the whole of India, and everywhere I have found society to
> be guided by local usages which are condemned by the Shrutis and
> Smritis. Popular customs, local usages, and observances prevalent
> among women only — have not these taken the place of the Smritis
> everywhere? Who obeys, and whom? If you can but spend enough money,
> the priest-class is ready to write out whatever sanctions or
> prohibitions you want! How many of them read the Vedic Kalpa (Ritual),
> Grihya and Shrauta Sutras? Then, look, here in Bengal the code of
> Raghunandana is obeyed; a little farther on you will find the code of
> Mitâkshâra in vogue; while in another part the code of Manu holds
> sway! You seem to think that the same laws hold good everywhere! What
> I want therefore is to introduce the study of the Vedas by stimulating
> a greater regard for them in the minds of the people, and to pass
> everywhere the injunctions of the Vedas.
>
> Disciple: Sir, is it possible nowadays to set them going?
>
> Swamiji: **It is true that all the ancient Vedic laws will not have a
> go, but if we introduce additions and alterations in them to suit the
> needs of the times, codify them, and hold them up as a new model to
> society,** why will they not pass current?
>
> Disciple: Sir, I was under the impression that at least the
> injunctions of Manu were being obeyed all over India even now.
>
> Swamiji: Nothing of the kind. Just look to your own province and see
> how the Vâmâchâra (immoral practices) of the Tantras has entered into
> your very marrow. Even modern Vaishnavism, which is the skeleton of
> the defunct Buddhism, is saturated with Vamachara! We must stem the
> tide of this Vamachara, which is contrary to the spirit of the Vedas.
>
> Disciple: Sir, is it possible now to cleanse this Aegean stable?
>
> Swamiji: What nonsense do you say, you coward! You have well-nigh
> thrown the country into ruin by crying, 'It is impossible, it is
> impossible!' What cannot human effort achieve?
>
> Disciple: But, sir, such a state of things seems impossible unless
> sages like Manu and Yâjnavalkya are again born in the country.
>
> Swamiji: Goodness gracious! Was it not purity and unselfish labour
> that made them Manu and Yajnavalkya, or was it something else? Well,
> we ourselves can be far greater than even Manu and Yajnavalkya if we
> try to; why will not our views prevail then?
>
> Disciple: Sir, it is you who said just now that we must revive the
> ancient usages and observances within the country. How then can we
> think lightly of sages like Manu and the rest?
>
> Swamiji: What an absurd deduction! You altogether miss my point. **I
> have only said that the ancient Vedic customs must be remodelled
> according to the need of the society and the times, and passed under a
> new form in the land.** Have I not?
>
> Disciple: Yes, sir.
>
> Swamiji: What, then, were you talking? You have read the Shastras, and
> my hope and faith rest in men like you. Understand my words in their
> true spirit, and apply yourselves to work in their light.
>
> Disciple: But, sir, who will listen to us? Why should our countrymen
> accept them?
>
> Swamiji: If you can truly convince them and practise what you preach,
> they must. If, on the contrary, like a coward you simply utter Shlokas
> as a parrot, be a mere talker and quote authority only, without
> showing them in action — then who will care to listen to you?
>
> Disciple: Please give me some advice in brief about social reform.
>
> Swamiji: Why, I have given you advice enough; now put at least
> something in practice. Let the world see that your reading of the
> scriptures and listening to me has been a success. **The codes of Manu
> and lots of other books that you have read — what is their basis and
> underlying purpose? Keeping that basis intact, compile in the manner
> of the ancient Rishis the essential truths of them and supplement them
> with thoughts that are suited to the times;** only take care that all
> races and all sects throughout India be really benefited by following
> these rules. **Just write out a Smriti like that; I shall revise it.**

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 7, Conversations and Dialogues, XI, From the Diary of a Disciple**

Comment: Thank you so much. Great conversation. I wish he had written that!

Comment: Welp classic liberal :(

Comment: why didn't Swami Vivekananda himself write such a Smriti, I wonder. What that gentleman said is true - the rishis have to do an avatar again to rewrite Smritis. It cannot be done by ordinary humans, nor do they have the right to do so.

Comment: The Swami died when he was only 39 years. No time to write a Smriti.

Comment: Any way the current Indian constitution and the various modern laws currently governing Hinduism may be considered as Smritis.